# What's the genus of a pair of pants?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I've been recently having a discussion on how to compute the genus of a pair of pants, namely the figure:

[image]

After some research, we stumbled across this webpage:

http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/model/euler.html

in which they find the genus of a three-holed sphere (i.e. a pair of pants) to be 2. However, the wikipedia article says it has genus 0.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)

For us, therefore, a satisfactory answer remains elusive. Our questions will then be: what are we missing? what is the right answer, if there is any (we hope so) ? What's the correct way to compute the genus of a pair of pants?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends. Is the pant material infinitely thin, or does it have thickness? Because an infinitely thin CD is tricky (i.e. it depends on your conventions), while a CD with thickness (a millimeter or so?) is undeniably a torus with genus 1. If the pants have thickness, then they are a double torus, with genus 2.

Comment: Ok in my mind I was considering a pair of pants with thickness, stretchable and malleable, but I didn't know this had important implications. As you say,  I thought that in this case a pair of pants was homeomorphic to a double torus, so it has genus 2. Thanks!

Comment: In the case of infinitely thin pants, however, how do you know it has genus 0? What are these conventions you are talking about?

Comment: One of these conventions are that the definition of genus is the maximal number of cuts you can do without disconnecting your object, and that a cut needs to be closed (have no end points). If the pants have no thickness, then a closed cut will always divide the pants into (at least) two parts, since a cut from one hole to the other won't be closed.

Comment: The first sentence of that wikipedia links says "A pair of pants is a surface". If you examine the mathematical definition of a surface, you will see that any "thickness" whatsoever is ruled out.

Comment: Furthermore, that pages.mtu.edu link is *not* talking about surfaces, it is talking about solids (and they are using the terminology "sphere" incorrectly, from a topologists points of view).

Comment: @Arthur's description of genus is correct, and you can also say that a surface has genus $0$ if and only if it can be embedded in the 2-dimensional sphere. To see why this is true for the pair of pants, cap off the waist and the two cuffs (by putting in three separate 2-dimensional discs) and you get a 2-dimensional sphere.